# load sqlite3 DB with data from external source (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am developing my first iPhone app, which includes an sqlite3 database that should contain approximately 1.200 records. These records are created by me.

During the tests i have created them in a .txt document and inserted the .txt into the database. This is a very inconvenient method to do this and i would just ask for some advice how to do this in a convenient way. I have been thinking about some external (free) databse, excel

Answer (score 0):

Use the mysqlite3 program on you *Mac*, to create the database. Then place the database into your App's bundle.

When you program launches, see if the database is in your app's "Documents" directory. If not, copy the one from the bundle to the Documents directory.

The mysqlite3 program on your Mac will generate a database which is compatible, and sufficient to use on your iOS device.

Comment: I cannot find the mysqlite3 program on my mac?

Comment: try this link to install it: http://snipplr.com/view/9360/installing-sqlite3-in-osx-leopard/

Comment: I found out that I can do sqlite3 commands already in the terminal, so i guess that means i have it installed. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: A question, how should i register data into the database, via the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You could use excel to create a csv (comma separated) file - then you'd just need to parse it.  If you already have the db started - you could also just use sqlite3 at the command line.